# Possible to pack a compressed archive into a .jar and uncompress it on startup?

Tags: java, jar, zip, compression, tar

The map data for my game is 100mb+, while when compressed is ~2mb.

Is it possible to uncompress / compress files from within a jar?

**EDIT:** jar's are already compressed, this was a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point; a jar file is a zip file (plus some meta data). If you simply add your uncompressed file to your jar it will be compressed, and adding a compressed file to a jar will generally lead to a larger file (you can't usually compress a compressed file).

Comment: I have not yet tried simply jarring it, I was just looking at in my workspace folder... This was a really stupid question. Sigh.